# Can we store the class object and not just the pointer to that object

Tags: c++, database, c++11, pointers, segmentation-fault

I was trying to store the class object in a file but as the class contains a vector of pointers which is causing a trouble because next time I am accessing the class I am able to fetch everything but this vector.

```
typedef vector<pair<int, MBR *>> vppint;

class Node{
private:
  int id;
  int parentID;
  int total_children;
  MBR *mbr;
  vppint children;
public:
  vppint fetchChildren(){
    return return this->children;
  }

  int totalChildren(){
    return this->total_children;
  }
};
```

MBR is some class.

after storing this Node class in the file and then reading it. the fetchChildren function throws segmentation fault with the obvious reason. is there any way to store the object and not just the pointer.

Comment: Do I miss something or why is the class defined twice?

Comment: The question is, is there a good reason for you to use pointers?

Comment: no, i don't want to use the pointer here. I just know this way to store values so i used it. I want to store the whole class object if possible.

Comment: Then don't use them, just ditch the pointers and the objects will be saved instead.

Comment: What code are you using to save it to a file? You need a serialisation library.

Comment: Is this a tree-like structure? Then you will likely not get away without any pointers, although `mbr` could likely be non-pointer. It seems more reasonable to have `std::vector<Node*>` instead (or `std::map<int, Node*>` if you need that int for something). It also seems that your question is about serialization/deserialization process (writing this struct to file and recovering it) rather than about pointers.

Comment: By 'store the whole class object' I guess you mean something like this `write(out, (char*)&node);`. If so then the bad news is that is not possible. You cannot write pointers to a file, you have to write enough information to reconstruct the object to the file and then you can recreate the pointer when you read back from the file.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can work with Constructors and Destructors if you would want to create / destroy an instance of a class (I believe those are not needed but it could help you understand how it works).

You can do so by declaring a public constructor in your node class. And then declare the function. `Node::Node()  {}` which in our case will be empty.

```
class Node{
private:
  int id;
  int parentID;
  int total_children;
  MBR *mbr;
  vppint children;
public:

  Node();
  vppint fetchChildren(){
    return return this->children;
  }

  int totalChildren(){
    return this->total_children;
  }
};
```

When you have a constructor which will initialize values (or if you prefer to not use a constructor) you can simply store the class object alike:

```
Node savedObject = Node(); // Creates an instance of the Node class.
```

If this is what you want to achieve I would suggest you read something as: https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_constructors.asp for more information.

Comment: `Node savedObject = Node(); // Creates an instance of the Node class.` Technically, all that's needed to create an instance of the Node class is `Node savedObject;`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius but wouldnt a non initialized `Node` result in a `nullpointer` when trying to access any of its members?

Comment: "_but wouldnt a non initialized `Node`_" What do you mean non-initialized? `Node savedObject;` invokes default constructor of `Node`. "_result in a `nullpointer` when trying to access any of its members?_" Where would the `nullpointer` be, when `savedObject` is a value?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius that is my bad, I must have confused something with Java. You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

That's C++. Until now you have to write your own serialization logic which handles pointers correctly. You can take a look at `boost::serialization`, what provides a lot of helper functions. Note that `boost::serialization` makes your serialization tool output platform dependet. If you want crossplatform serialization, you have to either put some more effort into your seriaization logic or make use of something like `protobuf`.